# Splitting the line in a CSV using C#

Tags: c#, regex, csv, split

I am reading a CSV file and a line reads like this

```
Context Tenant: {Vendor: 1, Customer: 719046046}","1,664,705.67","","7/11/2017 4:55 PM"
```

Now i would like to split this and collect each values in a Array.

```
value[0] should be Context Tenant: {Vendor: 1, Customer: 719046046}
value[1] should be 1,664,705.67
value[2] should be 7/11/2017 4:55 PM.
```

Tried using Regex and Split

```
var values = line1.Split(new char[] { '\\', '"' ,','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var values = Regex.Split(line1, "\\,");
```

However i am unable to read the value as i expected. Can you please share some light.

Comment: well your `value[0]` has a comma in it, and you dont seem to account for that, so its definitely going to split that string up

Comment: why not use some csv parser?

Comment: May be you are right @Jonesopolis, but i need to get this through...

Comment: seems like separator is `","` - not '\\', '"' ,','

Comment: @LeiYang: Thanks, I am already half way and i don't like to look into csv parser just for reading this line

Comment: Well, you probably should. CSV is a deceptively simple format, but if your data has embedded commas, it's really not something you can easily handle with regular expressions.

Comment: The double quotes are supposed to wrap around embedded commas.  I think the example data must have a missing double quote `"`, perhaps at the very beginning(?).  Otherwise, it's just not possible to magically decide which commas are "embedded" and which are delimiters.  Any attempt at an answer without well-formed data will be futile and just continue to fail on exceptions.  Any strict, reliable parser would give value 1 `Context Tenant: {Vendor: 1`, value 2 `Customer: 719046046},1`, value 3) `664`, value 4) `705.67`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the job. This version will remove the empty spaces

```
string [] n_new = g.Split(new string[] { "\",\""}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

To get rid of the starting end end `"` you can put an additional `Trim` before the Split:

```
string [] ret = g.Trim('"').Split(new string[] { "\",\""}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: i think we are almost there. However i forgot to mention you that there are other lines where the line starts with "... :(

Comment: @Mahesh so you have an additional `"` in the beginning of the first element?

Comment: @Mahesh I made an edit and put a trim in the command, check it out

Answer (score 0):

Because some of your elements contains commas I'd suggest splitting specifically on `","`, so use this in your split statement: `"\",\""`. So you should end up with:

`var values = Regex.Split(line1, "\",\"");`

And then to solve your issues of including `"` in the results, consider:

```
foreach (string value in string[] values)
    value = value.Replace("\"\"", "");
```

to get rid of all the unwanted extra double quotes (`"`). Sort of hacky but it should do the trick.

Comment: As stated below i also have few lines where the starting character is " and thus using the logic you mentioned "\ is captured in the first index

Comment: ? It isn't though. The way `Regex.Split()` works is it takes the second argument as a string and whenever it hits that _exact_ match it splits the string. For example if my argument is 'xxx' and my string is 'CatxDogxxRatxxxBird' then the result will be 'CatxDogxxRat' and 'Bird'. It only splits on 'xxx'. Only the full parameter will cause a split, not fractions of it.

Unless I'm failing to interpret what you're saying.

Comment: @CapnJack  What Mahesh is saying is that if a line begins with a double quote `"`, then that character is included in the first element returned by Split.  Your explanation only emphasizes that this will happen.  Apparently, Mahesh does not want the first double quote character included in the split output.